# Verifying a 3 bit end-around rotation in C++

Tags: c++, c, rotation

I need to do a 3 bit left end around rotation in C++.

So far I have:

```
A[i] = (A[i] << 3)|(A[i] >> 5);
```

A is an unsigned char array.

Is this correct? If not how can I fix it? Also what is the best way to test and see if this is correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me.

If you really want to test it, work out a bunch of inputs and outputs by hand and check your program produces them.

Or devise another method that you're absolutely sure will produce results (*eg* convert unsigned char to binary string, rotate the string, convert back to unsigned char) and compare the two against all 256 possible inputs.